# Can we install Linux version of Java on Cygwin?

Tags: java, cygwin

I am running a Java application on Cygwin however it is failing since it is pointing to the Java installed on the host windows machine. Therefore I was checking if we can install Java on Cygwin directly, ideally Linux Java (*but I do not think Linus version of Java could be possible*).

Please guide.

Comment: [That's a strange question.](https://xyproblem.info/) Why would you need that? I don't think anyone has built java on cygwin. You can run Linux java under wsl2, which is probably preferable to cygwin nowadays.

Comment: No, you can't, because Cygwin cannot run native Linux programs. It's just a shell that enables you to use Linux commands on Windows, but the code behind the commands has to be compiled for Windows. Nowadays there is [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) (WSL) which allows you to run Linux-native software on Windows.

Comment: My guess is that the application is failing because you are giving it Cygwin file paths.  Only programs built for Cygwin understand Cygwin file paths.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not work.
As reported at very begin of the project Webpage
https://cygwin.com/

> Cygwin is:
>
> - a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.
> - a DLL (cygwin1.dll) which provides substantial POSIX API functionality.
>
> Cygwin **is not**:
>
> - **a way to run native Linux apps on Windows**. You must rebuild your application from source if you want it to run on Windows.
> - a way to magically make native Windows apps aware of UNIX® functionality like signals, ptys, etc. Again, you need to build your
>   apps from source if you want to take advantage of Cygwin
>   functionality.